# Why is C's void type not analogous to the empty/bottom type?

Tags: type-theory, c

Wikipedia as well as other sources that I have found list C's `void` type as a unit type as opposed to an empty type. I find this confusing as it seems to me that `void` better fits the definition of an empty/bottom type.

- No values inhabit `void`, as far as I can tell.
- A function with a return type of void specifies that the function does not return anything and thus can only perform some side-effect.
- A pointer of type `void*` is a subtype of all other pointer types. Also, conversions to and from `void*` in C are implicit.

I am not sure if the last point has any merit as an argument for `void` being an empty type, as `void*` is more or less a special case with not much relation to `void`.

On the other hand, `void` itself is not a subtype of all other types, which as far as I can tell is a requirement for a type to be a bottom type.

Comment: By "does not return anything" you actually mean "does not return anything of interest", whereas a function with output empty does not return at all (i.e. crashes or loops infinitely).

Comment: As a return type, void is a unit type.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In C, `void` is used for multiple unrelated things. Depending on what it's used for, its meaning may be a unit type, an empty type, or something else.

When `void` is used by itself (as opposed to `void*`, a pointer to void), it's a unit type, i.e. a type with a single value. Functions that return `void` are said to “return nothing”, but what this really means is that they don't return any information. They return $0$ bits of information, which means that they return a value of a type that contains $2^0 = 1$ distinct values, i.e. a unit type.

This is not an empty type: a function that returns an empty type cannot return a value, since there is no value of that type. A function whose return type is empty can only loop forever, or abort the program, or raise an exception (`longjmp`) (or otherwise arrange not to return, e.g. by transferring control to another thread or process using functionality beyond standard C). To keep things confusing, it is conventional in C to use `void` in lieu of an empty type (C doesn't have an empty type).

The `void` type requires $0$ bits of storage. Because C insists on every object occupying a whole, nonzero number of bytes of storage, it's forbidden to create an object of type `void`, and there's a special syntax to return the `void` value (a `return` statement with the value omitted). There's no syntax that yields the value of type `void`, but that value is there whenever a function whose return type is `void` returns.

C does not have a bottom type in the sense of allowing any possible type. Even incomplete types specify the general nature of its values, e.g. pointers or structs or unions or functions. But `void*` is a pointer to any non-function type: it's the least element of the algebra of object pointer types, i.e. it's the bottom object pointer type. Unlike the general case of `T*` where `T` is some non-void type, `void*` is not the type of pointers to a value of type `void`, but the type of pointers to a value of unspecified type.

Comment: One can return void in C++ and C89. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987493/return-void-type-in-c-and-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The 4th paragraph is formally wrong. In C, the amount of storage for `void` is undefined, not zero. This is not the reason why objects of type `void` are disallowed. The formal reason is that `void` is an _incomplete type_, and objects cannot have an incomplete type.

Comment: @MSalters No, that's not right. You are just making up the meaning of the term architecture. I can write a C compiler that can target both stanard x86 or amd architectures and Java bytecode. There's *nothing* preventing me to do so, it's just a lot of work to produce the final result. And the choice of what `void *` means has **nothing** to do with the final instructions, it's a completely arbitrary decision that has nothing to do with the final architecture. This compiler could have an option switch that changes the interpretation of `void *`, there's nothing preventing this.

Comment: @MSalters No, what I wrote is formally correct. “Because” refers to the motivation for the language design, not to the logical inferences inside the language specification. The `void` type *requires* 0 bits of storage. This is the reason why the designers of C decided to make `void` an incomplete type, as opposed to defining it taking 0 bytes of storage (which would have a lot of impact on the language design) or 1 byte of storage (which would waste space).

Comment: @Gilles: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense either. If allowed, the space used would be 1 byte _per object of void type_, and you obviously don't need many objects of `void` type.  Not to mention that these objects could alias all other objects, so the actual usage would be zero anyway.

Comment: @MSalters If you maintain the pretty useful property that `TYPE1 x1; TYPE2 x2; assert(&x1 != &x2)` then every object has to use at least one byte of address space. You could get away with not allocating storage for those objects, only address space, but it gets pretty hard for a compiler to manage this.

Comment: @Gilles: That's not a property which C guarantees (it doesn't even compile, ignoring the trivial case where TYPE1 and TYPE2 differ in cv-qualification only). But let's assume`void x1, x2;` is allowed, and we'd want `x1!=x2`. This could make sense - creating unique addresses is in fact why `malloc(0)` is explicitly allowed. And using two bytes for that would be significantly better than the `malloc(0)` approach of generating unique addresses.

Comment: In Rust, *unit* is a zero-sized type which enables some nice implementation techniques, such as implementing a set as a map where the value type is unit without introducing an overhead. Taking the address of a zero-sized value, always returns a fixed reserved address. Of course that design decision sacrifices the "unique address per field" property and it'd cause problems for `offsetof`, so the C/C++ choice of disallowing it is understandable as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Well, C++ actually allows empty structs, i.e. `struct E { };`. When used as a base class, this can be zero-sized. (There's really no such thing as C/C++, the two languages make their own choices and they can differ in these areas. C obviously doesn't have empty base classes, as it doesn't have OO in the first place)

Comment: "C doesn't have an empty type" Well, C11 has `_Noreturn void foo(void)`, which is close.

Comment: The failure of the C Standards Committee to accommodate zero-sized types needlessly complicates some other aspects of the language specification, and makes some practical tasks needlessly difficult.  I wonder what real problems were avoided by not generalizing the fact that an N-byte object has N+1 associated addresses, including N "pointers to storage" and N "pointers just past storage".  No "pointer to storage" for any object will compare equal to any "pointer to storage" for any other object, and likewise for comparisons between "pointers just past storage" for different object.

Comment: Generalizing, a zero-sized object would have one address, but it wouldn't happen to be a "pointer to storage" nor a "pointer just past storage", and there would thus be no rule saying in which cases it would compare equal or unequal to any other pointer.

Answer (score 11):

The name “empty type” is perhaps confusing. What this means is, as you say yourself, *the type contains no values*. The “empty” refers not to any individual values of the type, it refers to the type as a whole, considered as a ~set of possible values. So this does **not** say something like “a function returning `void` returns no information”, but “there *exists* no value of type `⊥`”.

This means a function whose result type is `⊥` can *never* terminate. If it did terminate, if would have to return a value of `⊥`, but, well, such a value doesn't exist.

It also means, it's not even possible to discuss how much information a value of empty type would contain, because there is no such value. (Or if you will, a nonsensical statement like “any value of empty type contains exactly 35093658 bits of information” is vacuously true.) It's somewhat useful (though not really correct) to think of `⊥` values as containing an *infinite* amount of information.

Whereas a C function with “return type” `void` clearly *can* return, but doesn't give you any information in its return value. Well, that's precisely what characterises a unit type: its values don't contain any information, because there is only one such value (hence you can always say what the return value will be, even without bothering to ever call the function).

[To quote Conor McBride](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115522/745903) (transliterated to C):

> `void` means "Boring". It means the boring type which contains one thing, also boring. There is nothing interesting to be gained by comparing one element of the boring type with another, because there is nothing to learn about an element of the boring type by giving it any of your attention.
>
> It is very different from the empty type [...]. The empty type is very exciting, because if somebody ever gives you a value belonging to it, you know that you are already dead and in Heaven and that anything you want is yours.

Comment: Interesting; if the definition of ⊥ is the function whose return type is ⊥ can never terminate, then C has such a type. We call it volatile void.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. [I doesn't seem to be actually standard-conformant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288603/what-does-or-did-volatile-void-function-do#), though.